# VF Page output link not rendering correctly

Tags: apex, visualforce, outputlink

I am outputting a table from a list in my controller using `apex:repeat`.

In one of my columns, I want to have a link that will open the record for detail view

I want a link like this `https://www.salesforce.com/apex/SystemChangeRequest?id=a3K8E0000000B7S`.

as my detail page is called `SystemChangeRequest` and the id of the record is a3K8E0000000B7S

so I have tried this:

```
<td>                
    <apex:outputLink value="/apex/SystemChangeRequest/?id=!{Requests.id}">!{Requests.id}</apex:outputLink>                  
</td>
```

But the link being rendered in the browser is:

```
https://cs87.salesforce.com/apex/SystemChangeRequest/?id=!%7BRequests.id%7D
```

so it is giving an 'invalid URL' error.

So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You messed up your merge field; it should be `{!Requests.Id}`. Once you fix that, it should be okay. As an aside, I usually prefer the `URLFOR` formula, which is future-proof (it constructs the URLs correctly for you). That would look like this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.SystemChangeRequest,null,[id=Requests.Id]}">
    {!Requests.Id}
</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: +1 for `URLFOR`.

Comment: N.B. merge field enclosed by `apex:outputLink` could be something more useful like `{!Requests.Name}` or some other user friendly value